# how to bind variable from controller to service for data property $resource angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngresource

I want to call this service from a controller. How can i bind "customVariable" for data?

```
app.factory('TagSrv', ['$resource', function($resource){

  return $resource(apiUrl+'api/tags/delete', {}, {
    "delete" : {
      method:'DELETE',
      data: [customVariable]
    }
  });

}]);
```

Comment: What do you mean by binding variable for data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant't, at least in this configuration, because custom $resource methods, AFAIK, accept following signature:

```
action: {method:?, params:?, isArray:?, headers:?, ..}
```

The only interesting parameter that I think can adapt to your case is if you can use your data as an URL parameter, then you can go with the `params` parameter, if it's not your case, you could go with a custom `$http` REST manager, but without knowing more on you REST endopoint it's difficult to come up with advices for a working implementation.

Source: [AngularJS $resource doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource)